# WCF return Class with object field

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract, datamember

I have a Wcf service that works as RestApi

```
[KnownType(typeof(myClass1))]
[KnownType(typeof(myClass2))]
[KnownType(typeof(myClassAndOther23typesOmmited))]
[DataContract]
public class ApiResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Success { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Result { get; private set; }
}
```

Field `Result` is problematic part, it cannot be serialized as it's an object type. So the question is, how to return proper `ApiResult` object.

#### Note

Althought there is `KnownTypeAttribute`, service throws **SerializationException** when i try to assign `string[]` to ApiResult `Result` field and return to client.

#### Upd

After trying `ApiResult<T>`
Service compiled successfully, and intellisense gives this
[image: Intellisense Suggestion for generic types]

After few investigations, gathered that those weird type names are made to avoid collisions in service (it's simple hashcode of type which were achieved by `GetHash()` of literally **object**),

This is responce to **nvoigt** solution as couldnt insert image to comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you create a generic ApiResult:

```
[DataContract]
public class ApiResult<T>
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Success { get; internal set; }

    [DataMember]
    public T Result { get; internal set; }
}
```

That way, your method can actually return a typed value like `ApiResult<myClass1>` and you don't need any `KnownType`s at all.

Comment: Im investigating this scenario by the time, but looks promising.

Comment: @evc that's your client side service reference wizard making sense of the WSDL description. If you want to use generics on the client side, too, you should have a contract assembly to share between client and service.

Comment: so if i choose this solution im gonna end up with dependency, and other clients (let's say mobile platforms) wont get consistent service to work with, btw thats not the way i want to move. is there any other solutions that my service would be acceptable for all other independent platforms?

Comment: @evc What exactly is inconsistent about it? If you use C# as client, you can have generics, if you don't or don't want contract dependencies, you will have to make use of the platform feature of choice. Most likely they will generate a type per generic type you use. How else would you do it, there are languages that don't have generics or handle generics differently. Generic type-safety is way better than just transferring an object, hoping the other side will know what was meant.

Comment: So u say that there is no really good solution to use without generics. And i literally must make my IIS server to be like gate between my wcf service and other platforms. right?

Comment: Well, hosting a WCF service in IIS is probably the standard way. What was your other option? Why would it not work with generics in your service?

Comment: Please help me to shape out our conversation. If i use generics at client side, i need to use shared assembly right. And i will probably use this client (Asp.Net WebApi + Angularjs) as gateway (because i wont use that hashed object type names)(And will have to configure cors). If i dont use generics at client side, i need to hardcode all my wcf stuff. But i can use WCF service directly from anywhere (just by url). Am i right?

Comment: I don't see why you *need* a shared assembly with generics. Only if you want generics at the client side. If you don't have a shared assembly, your wizard will generate working non-generic types from your WSDL. Maybe you can try generics and post an actual problem when you use them, that would make it a lot easier to talk about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58304/discussion-between-evc-and-nvoigt).